# Vue List update after set new values

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, axios

I am working with Vue 2 and I have a rendered list. I load a modal to update each. After successfully ajax-request I want to update the values also in the list.

But that´s not working. Here is my code.

```
<tr v-for="(setting, index) in list" :item="setting" :index="index">
  <td> {{ setting.key}} </td>
  <td> {{ setting.description }} </td>
  <td>....
```

And here is my update method with axios.

```
update(setting, index){
  const data = this;
   axios.patch('/admin/setting/' + setting.id, setting).then(function 
       (response){
    if(response.data.ok === true){
      alert('Saved');
 //        self.list[index].description = 'djijdiejii';
 //        self.list[index].value = '9900';
 //        console.log(self.list[index]);
      Vue.set(data.list, index, {description: 'Test', value: 9999})
                }
            }).catch(function(error){
                console.error(error);
            })
        }
```

Can anybody help me?

That´s a component and it´s imported to the Vue Instance. Maybe that´s a problem?

Comment: Set unique keys for `v-for` elements: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key

Comment: no difference. On my vue Object all is changed. But the rendered list does not change.

Comment: Do you've Vue dev tool in chrome? It can help you find bugs like this.

Comment: Yes. In my devTools the Vue List has the new values. I tried also with an computed list. The values there are always the new ones. But my list is not updated...

Comment: Try `data.$set(data.list, index, {description: 'Test', value: 9999})` instead of `Vue.set(data.list, index, {description: 'Test', value: 9999})`

Comment: no change - still the same result. No error  in console

Comment: What keys did you bind to `v-for` elements? These keys should be unique, so that Vue can see the difference. For example, array index is NOT a valid key - it stays the same no matter the element is updated or not. Try `:key="setting.key"` or something similar.

Comment: <tr v-for="(setting, index, key) in list" :setting="setting" :index="index" :key="setting.id" >  -> Console.log after update -> key is undefined

Comment: Soooo.. I have found the error. Because i loaded the setting via property! Now I have switched to load via ajax after mounted and it works fine without Vue.set ...